# How to send sms at regular interval to preselected contacts?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I want this app to function like this
1.it will send the user location along with a message at interval of 2 mins to preselected contacts.
2.Location should be as presice as possible.
3.it should run in backround.
4.it stops only when the user stops it.

I tried many ways but it would work in foreground I want this to waork even when the app is closed if the user has to stop it he would have to open the app and deactivate it.

Comment: please care to share what have you done so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntentService class provides a straightforward structure for running an operation on a single background thread

See https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html